# Custom LdapUserDetailsService always fails to match passwords in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, bcrypt

i'm currently building a custom LdapUserDetailsService for my Spring boot Application. Before i used the custom UserDetailsService i used the ldap Authentication function of the AuthenticationManagerBuilder class.
My custom userDetailsService extends the LdapUserDetailsService. I initiate the class as follows:

```
public CustomLdapUserDetailsService(LdapContextSource contextSource, ServerSettings serverSettings) {
        super(setLdapUserSearch(contextSource, serverSettings), setDefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, serverSettings));
    }

    private static LdapUserSearch setLdapUserSearch(LdapContextSource contextSource, ServerSettings serverSettings) {
        LdapSettings ldapSettings = serverSettings.getSecurity().getLdap();
        return new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(ldapSettings.getUserSearchBase(), ldapSettings.getUserSearchFilter(), contextSource);


    }

    private static DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator setDefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(LdapContextSource contextSource, ServerSettings serverSettings) {
        LdapSettings ldapSettings = serverSettings.getSecurity().getLdap();
        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator defaultAuthoritiesPopulator = new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource, ldapSettings.getGroupSearchBase());
        defaultAuthoritiesPopulator.setGroupSearchFilter(ldapSettings.getGroupSearchBase());
        return defaultAuthoritiesPopulator;
    }
```

The ServerSettings Object is use here is the same object i used before to configure the ldap object of the AuthenticationManagerBuilder.
However, now with my custom ldap authenticator authentication always failes because of invalid credentials. (I checked the credentails - they are the right ones! =D).
So what i did was checking the match() method of the BCryptPasswordEncoder. I retrieved the rawPassword (GoodNewsEveryone) and the encodedPassword ($2a$10$YsCMR1SguyMe31DsWof0v.8Pr3rHWKzSZEud.tqnO0ZO2Kx4XjXsy) and checked on bcrypt-generator.com if they match. Of course they don't (even though the password is the correct one!)

As for now i'm not quite sure where the error could be so maybe there is someone who as had the same issue or who knows where the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, i found it out. For anyone who runs into the same issue:
When adding your custom UserDetailsService to your security config, you need to add a password decoder. LDAP itself does not use encdoings like bcrypt but a sha algorithm. So just add a sha password encoder and it should work.
You do this by first calling the addUserDetailsService method of AuthenticationManagerBuilder and then the passwordDencoder method to which you add your Password-Decoder as an argument.